# Cannot borrow as mutable more than once at a time in one code - but can in another very similar

Tags: rust

I've this snippet that doesn't pass the borrow checker:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

enum Error {
    FunctionNotFound,
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Function<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
    code: &'a [u32],
}

struct Context<'a> {
    program: HashMap<&'a str, Function<'a>>,
    call_stack: Vec<Function<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Context<'a> {
    fn get_function(&'a mut self, fun_name: &'a str) -> Result<Function<'a>, Error> {
        self.program
            .get(fun_name)
            .map(|f| *f)
            .ok_or(Error::FunctionNotFound)
    }

    fn call(&'a mut self, fun_name: &'a str) -> Result<(), Error> {
        let fun = try!(self.get_function(fun_name));

        self.call_stack.push(fun);

        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `self.call_stack` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:29:9
   |
27 |         let fun = try!(self.get_function(fun_name));
   |                        ---- first mutable borrow occurs here
28 | 
29 |         self.call_stack.push(fun);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
...
32 |     }
   |     - first borrow ends here
```

My gut feeling is that the problem is tied to the fact that `HashMap` returns either `None` or a reference of the value inside the data structure. But I don't want that: my intention is that `self.get_function` should return either a byte copy of the stored value or an error (that's why I put `.map(|f| *f)`, and `Function` is `Copy`).

Changing `&'a mut self` to something else doesn't help.

However, the following snippet, somewhat similar in spirit, is accepted:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Error {
    StackUnderflow,
}

struct Context {
    stack: Vec<u32>,
}

impl Context {
    fn pop(&mut self) -> Result<u32, Error> {
        self.stack.pop().ok_or(Error::StackUnderflow)
    }

    fn add(&mut self) -> Result<(), Error> {
        let a = try!(self.pop());
        let b = try!(self.pop());

        self.stack.push(a + b);
        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = Context { stack: vec![1, 2] };
    a.add().unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", a.stack);
}
```

Now I'm confused. What is the problem with the first snippet? Why doesn't it happen in the second?

The snippets are part of a larger piece of code. In order to provide more context, [this on the Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e2c360eb91f7e0e459e7&version=stable) shows a more complete example with the faulty code, and [this shows an earlier version without `HashMap`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f6152f3411c1effed810&version=stable), which passes the borrow checker and runs normally.

Comment: I don't think `fun_name` should have any lifetime.

Comment: your second snippet has no lifetimes at all, so it doesn't really qualify for "similar"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have fallen into the lifetime-trap. Adding the same lifetime to more references will constrain your program more. Adding more lifetimes and giving each reference the minimal possible lifetime will permit more programs. As @o11c notes, removing the constraints to the `'a` lifetime will solve your issue.

```
impl<'a> Context<'a> {
    fn get_function(&mut self, fun_name: &str) -> Result<Function<'a>, Error> {
        self.program
            .get(fun_name)
            .map(|f| *f)
            .ok_or(Error::FunctionNotFound)
    }

    fn call(&mut self, fun_name: &str) -> Result<(), Error> {
        let fun = try!(self.get_function(fun_name));

        self.call_stack.push(fun);

        Ok(())
    }
}
```

The reason this works is that Rust inserts new lifetimes, so in the compiler your function's signatures will look like this:

```
fn get_function<'b>(&'b mut self, fun_name: &'b str) -> Result<Function<'a>, Error>
fn call<'b>(&'b mut self, fun_name: &'b str) -> Result<(), Error>
```

Always try to not use any lifetimes and let the compiler be smart. If that fails, don't spray lifetimes everywhere, think about where you want to pass ownership, and where you want to limit the lifetime of a reference.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to put `fn get_function<'b>(&'b mut self, fun_name: &'b str) -> Result<Function<'b>, Error> {` but the error became even more strange. It seems `Function` can't have the same lifetime as `fun_name` in this method, but I don't really *understand* why.

Comment: i don't know why you would want to constrain the lifetime. Usually you try to free the lifetimes as much as possible, the compiler is constraining you enough.

Comment: Also I'm guessing your `name` field's lifetime could be `'static` instead of `'a`. If that's not possible, there's a good chance you wanted that field to be a `String` instead. The same goes for the `HashMap`'s key-type.

Comment: I wanted to allocate all such strings in a `TypedArena` and just have `&str` references to it, but I think you're right. They can't be `'static` though, because I want to generate the code using a compiler.

Comment: *Adding more lifetimes and giving each reference the minimal possible lifetime will **permit more programs*** — that logic seems backwards; did you mean *less* programs?

Comment: Maybe I should remove that statement entirely. I meant that you can call the function from more contexts

Answer (score 8):

You only need to remove unnecessary lifetime qualifiers in order for your code to compile:

```
fn get_function(&mut self, fun_name: &str) -> Result<Function<'a>, Error> { ... }

fn call(&mut self, fun_name: &str) -> Result<(), Error> { ... }
```

Your problem was that you tied the lifetime of `&mut self` and the lifetime of the value stored in it (`Function<'a>`), which is in most cases unnecessary. With this dependency which was present in `get_function()` definition, the compiler had to assume that the result of the call `self.get_function(...)` borrows `self`, and hence it prohibits you from borrowing it again.

Lifetime on `&str` argument is also unnecessary - it just limits the possible set of argument values for no reason. Your key can be a string with arbitrary lifetime, not just `'a`.