# Can't reference a slice of &str because it doesn't live long enough, even though what it references does

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm implementing a scanner in Rust. I have a `scan` method on a `Scanner` struct which takes a string slice as the source code, breaks that string into a `Vec<&str>` of UTF-8 characters (using the crate [`unicode_segmentation`](https://unicode-rs.github.io/unicode-segmentation/unicode_segmentation/index.html)), and then delegates each char to a `scan_token` method which determines its lexical token and returns it.

```
extern crate unicode_segmentation;
use unicode_segmentation::UnicodeSegmentation;

struct Scanner {
    start: usize,
    current: usize,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Token<'src> {
    lexeme: &'src [&'src str],
}

impl Scanner {
    pub fn scan<'src>(&mut self, source: &'src str) -> Vec<Token<'src>> {
        let mut offset = 0;
        let mut tokens = Vec::new();
        // break up the code into UTF8 graphemes
        let chars: Vec<&str> = source.graphemes(true).collect();
        while let Some(_) = chars.get(offset) {
            // determine which token this grapheme represents
            let token = self.scan_token(&chars);
            // push it to the tokens array
            tokens.push(token);
            offset += 1;
        }
        tokens
    }

    pub fn scan_token<'src>(&mut self, chars: &'src [&'src str]) -> Token<'src> {
        // get this lexeme as some slice of the slice of chars
        let lexeme = &chars[self.start..self.current];
        let token = Token { lexeme };
        token
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut scanner = Scanner {
        start: 0,
        current: 0,
    };
    let tokens = scanner.scan("abcd");
    println!("{:?}", tokens);
}
```

The error I receive is:

```
error[E0597]: `chars` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:22:42
   |
22 |             let token = self.scan_token(&chars);
   |                                          ^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
28 |     }
   |     - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'src as defined on the method body at 15:17...
  --> src/main.rs:15:17
   |
15 |     pub fn scan<'src>(&mut self, source: &'src str) -> Vec<Token<'src>> {
   |                 ^^^^
```

I suppose I understand the logic behind why this doesn't work: the error makes it clear that `chars` needs to live as long as lifetime `'src`, because `tokens` contains slice references into the data inside `chars`.

What I don't understand is, since `chars` is just a slice of references into an object which *does* have a lifetime of `'src` (namely `source`), why can't `tokens` reference this data after `chars` has been dropped? I'm fairly new to low-level programming and I suppose my intuition regarding references + lifetimes might be somewhat broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can be reduced to this:

```
pub fn scan<'a>(source: &'a str) -> Option<&'a str> {
    let chars: Vec<&str> = source.split("").collect();
    scan_token(&chars)
}

pub fn scan_token<'a>(chars: &'a [&'a str]) -> Option<&'a str> {
    chars.last().cloned()
}
```

```
error[E0597]: `chars` does not live long enough
 --> src/lib.rs:3:17
  |
3 |     scan_token(&chars)
  |                 ^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
4 | }
  | - borrowed value only lives until here
  |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the function body at 1:13...
 --> src/lib.rs:1:13
  |
1 | pub fn scan<'a>(source: &'a str) -> Option<&'a str> {
  |             ^^
```

The `scan_token` function requires that the reference to the slice and the references inside the slice have the **same** lifetime: `&'a [&'a str]`. Since the `Vec` lives for a shorter period of time, that's what the unified lifetime must be. However, the lifetime of the vector isn't long enough to return the value.

Remove the unneeded lifetime:

```
pub fn scan_token<'a>(chars: &[&'a str]) -> Option<&'a str>
```

---

Applying these changes to your complete code, you see the core problem is repeated in the definition of `Token`:

```
struct Token<'src> {
    lexeme: &'src [&'src str],
}
```

This construction makes it definitely not possible for your code to compile as-is — there is no vector of slices that lives as long as the slices. Your code is simply not possible in this form.

You *could* pass in a mutable reference to a `Vec` to use as storage, but this would be pretty unusual and has plenty of downsides you'd hit when you try to do anything larger:

```
impl Scanner {
    pub fn scan<'src>(&mut self, source: &'src str, chars: &'src mut Vec<&'src str>) -> Vec<Token<'src>> {
        // ...
        chars.extend(source.graphemes(true));
        // ...
        while let Some(_) = chars.get(offset) {
            // ...
            let token = self.scan_token(chars);
            // ...
        }
        // ...
    }

    // ...    
}

fn main() {
    // ...
    let mut chars = Vec::new();
    let tokens = scanner.scan("abcd", &mut chars);
    // ...
}
```

You probably just want `Token` to be `Vec<&'src str>`

See also:

- [Cannot borrow as mutable more than once at a time in one code - but can in another very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31067031/155423)
- [Is there any way to return a reference to a variable created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32682876/155423)

Comment: To clarify - no vector of slices can live as long as the slices it references because, by defintion, a vector must always be dropped before the slices inside it are?

Comment: @jonny Edited to clarify what I meant by "no vector".

Comment: @jonny Your slices have 'src lifetime but your vector is created&dropped inside "scan" function, which is a block will be executed in shorter lifetime than 'src, you can see this by setting explicit lifetime on your function ->  `fn scan_token<'src,'b>(chars: &'b [&'src str]) -> Option<&'src str>` ( 'src > 'b )