# Why does returning a mutable reference from a method prevent calling any other methods, even when the reference goes out of scope?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I want to write a simple key/value store that can store anything. I started with a small wrapper around a `HashMap`:

```
use std::any::{Any, TypeId};
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Pair<'a> {
    key: &'a str,
    value: Box<Any>,
    data_type: TypeId,
}

impl<'a> Pair<'a> {
    fn new<T>(k: &'a str, v: T) -> Self
    where
        T: Any + 'static,
    {
        Self {
            key: k,
            value: Box::new(v),
            data_type: TypeId::of::<T>(),
        }
    }

    fn update<T>(&mut self, new_value: T)
    where
        T: Any + 'static,
    {
        self.data_type = TypeId::of::<T>();
        self.value = Box::new(new_value);
    }

    fn get<T>(&'a self) -> &'a T
    where
        T: Any + 'static,
    {
        self.value.downcast_ref::<T>().unwrap()
    }

    fn get_mut<T>(&'a mut self) -> &'a mut T
    where
        T: Any + 'static,
    {
        self.value.downcast_mut::<T>().unwrap()
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Database<'a> {
    data: HashMap<&'a str, Pair<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Database<'a> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            data: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    fn insert(&mut self, data: Pair<'a>) {
        self.data.insert(data.key, data);
    }

    fn find(&self, key: &str) -> &'a Pair {
        self.data.get(key).unwrap()
    }

    fn find_mut(&mut self, key: &str) -> &'a mut Pair {
        self.data.get_mut(key).unwrap()
    }

    fn remove(&mut self, key: &str) {
        self.data.remove(key);
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Position {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut db = Database::new();

    // add data
    {
        let pair1 = Pair::new("testkey", "Awesome string...".to_owned());
        let pair2 = Pair::new("position", Position { x: 0.0, y: 0.0 });

        db.insert(pair1);
        db.insert(pair2);
    }

    // change data
    {
        let pair = db.find_mut("position");
        pair.get_mut::<Position>().x = 50.0;
    } // <--- end of &mut Pair

    // read data
    let pos = db.find("position");

    println!("{:?}", pos);
}
```

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `db` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
   --> src/main.rs:101:15
    |
96  |         let pair = db.find_mut("position");
    |                    -- mutable borrow occurs here
...
101 |     let pos = db.find("position");
    |               ^^
    |               |
    |               immutable borrow occurs here
    |               mutable borrow later used here
```

I don't understand the borrow checker here. I scoped everything so `pair` don't exist by `db.find("position")`. Why does it not work? If I understand the documentation correctly, it's to use mutable vars in a nested scope.

I wrote a simpler example, I came from:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut x = 5;

    {
        let y = &mut x;
        *y = 10;
    }

    println!("{}", x);
}
```

This works as expected. I'm really stuck with the borrow checker.

Comment: If you can, use an owned string. It will remove a lot of difficulties.

Comment: @DarthBoiethios You mean key: String instead of key: &str?

Comment: Yes, that will remove all your `'a` lifetimes that spread around.

Comment: I think you're right. It makes no sense to store a reference to str... as a key. The can stand alone owned by the pair struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR

```
fn get<T>(&self) -> &T
fn get_mut<T>(&mut self) -> &mut T

fn find(&self) -> &Pair<'a>
fn find_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Pair<'a>
```

---

Creating a [MCVE](/help/mcve) is a vitally important skill to being an effective programmer. We catalog Rust-specific techniques on [the tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info). Here's one for your code:

```
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct Pair<'a>(&'a str);

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct Database<'a> {
    data: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> Database<'a> {
    fn find(&self) -> &'a Pair {
        unimplemented!()
    }

    fn find_mut(&mut self) -> &'a mut Pair {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut db = Database::default();
    {
        db.find_mut();
    }
    db.find();
}
```

The problem occurs because you've sprinkled lifetimes about without them being correct. Specifically:

```
fn find(&self) -> &'a Pair
fn find_mut(&mut self) -> &'a mut Pair
```

These methods say that they are going to return a reference **to a `Pair`** that lasts as long as the data you inserted into the `Database`. This cannot be true because the data you've inserted is a `&'static str`.

You actually want:

```
fn find(&self) -> &Pair<'a>
fn find_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Pair<'a>
```

Adding `#![deny(rust_2018_idioms)]` to your crate helps catch these, although the error messages aren't perfect yet:

```
error: hidden lifetime parameters in types are deprecated
  --> src/main.rs:12:27
   |
12 |     fn find(&self) -> &'a Pair {
   |                           ^^^^- help: indicate the anonymous lifetime: `<'_>`

error: hidden lifetime parameters in types are deprecated
  --> src/main.rs:16:39
   |
16 |     fn find_mut(&mut self) -> &'a mut Pair {
   |                                       ^^^^- help: indicate the anonymous lifetime: `<'_>`
```

If we then expand back out to the complete original problem, we see that the problem still hasn't gone away. Since we just had an issue with the lifetime inside of `Pair`, let's look to see if there are any more related issues:

```
fn get<T>(&'a self) -> &'a T
fn get_mut<T>(&'a mut self) -> &'a mut T
```

This states that `self` will live as long as `self.key`, which is not what you want 99% of the time. Remove these explcit lifetimes to allow normal lifetime elision to take place:

```
fn get<T>(&self) -> &T
fn get_mut<T>(&mut self) -> &mut T
```

See also:

- [Cannot borrow as mutable more than once at a time in one code - but can in another very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31067031/155423)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I think I've to read the chapter about lifetimes one more time.

Comment: When I read `deny rust_2018_idioms` I am thinking that those idioms are now denied, when actually it's enforcing them. Hum... :D

Comment: @MatthieuM. yeah, I don't like it either. I feel like I've heard some argument about why it makes sense with this polarity, but I don't recall it now.