# How to infer an appropriate lifetime for an implementation using lifetimes for structs and impl?

Tags: rust, lifetime

How do I resolve this error? What exactly am I telling the compiler when I use the "anonymous lifetime" in `impl`?

```
struct LineHandlerInfo<'a> {
    label: &'a str,
    match_literal: &'a str,
    f: fn(&str) -> Option<&str>,
}

struct Game<'a> {
    handlers: Vec<LineHandlerInfo<'a>>,
}

impl Game<'_> {
    fn match_str<'a>(
        &'a mut self,
        label: &'a str,
        match_literal: &'a str,
        mut f: fn(&str) -> Option<&str>,
    ) {
        let mut lh = LineHandlerInfo {
            label,
            match_literal,
            f,
        };
        self.handlers.push(lh);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut g = Game {
        handlers: Vec::new(),
    };
    g.match_str("echo hello", "hello", |s| {
        println!("{}", s);
        None
    });
}
```

When I attempt to compile, I get the following error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'a` due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:18:22
   |
18 |         let mut lh = LineHandlerInfo {
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime 'a as defined on the method body at 12:18...
  --> src/main.rs:12:18
   |
12 |     fn match_str<'a>(
   |                  ^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:19:13
   |
19 |             label,
   |             ^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime '_ as defined on the impl at 11:11...
  --> src/main.rs:11:11
   |
11 | impl Game<'_> {
   |           ^^
   = note: ...so that the expression is assignable:
           expected LineHandlerInfo<'_>
              found LineHandlerInfo<'_>
```

How do I resolve this error and what exactly am I telling the compiler when I specify a lifetime on `impl Game` when I already have a lifetime on the struct?

Comment: based reading links from @shepmaster and with a lot of trial and error, I've fixed the compiler error; https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=208beb18e2530b97f5ccf15102790a63 -- would be nice to have some more reference to what exactly this syntax is mean to convey

Comment: I removed the other variation I tried which @shepmaster says is a different issue -- leaving here for reference: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=00449a690ba597eccc405ef1f8a951a8)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> How do I resolve this error and what exactly am I telling the compiler when I specify a lifetime on impl Game when I already have a lifetime on the struct?

I suspect your confusion stems from an incomplete understanding of the way in which lifetimes are declared and used in Rust.

## Struct Lifetimes

In order to use a lifetime on a struct, you *declare* the lifetime inside the `<>` adjacent to the name of the struct you are declaring, and then *refer* to that lifetime inside the struct definition. Importantly, note that the lifetime declared there is scoped to the struct definition - it has no meaning outside.

For example (using the MRE that @Shepmaster provided):

```
struct Game<'a> {
    handlers: Vec<&'a str>,
}
```

The struct `Game` contains a vector of references to strings, and the strings which are referenced must last at least as long as the `Game` struct.

## Impl Lifetimes

When using a lifetime specifier on an impl block, you *declare* the lifetime inside the `<>` adjacent to the impl keyword, after which you may *refer* to the lifetime both in the struct being implemented, and inside the implementation itself, like this:

```
impl<'b> Game<'b> {
    fn match_str(&mut self, label: &'b str) {
        self.handlers.push(label);
    }
}
```

Note that I am using an entirely different lifetime name here (`'b`) to illustrate that the the lifetime declaration on the struct is independent of the one on the impl block.

Breaking this down:

```
impl<'b>
```

This means that we are defining an implementation for a struct, and within that definition we will use the lifetime `'b`

```
 Game<'b> {
```

This means that the impl is for the struct `Game` with lifetime `'b` - so any references to `self` inside this implementation are going to automatically have lifetime `'b` as well.

```
fn match_str(&mut self, label: &'b str) {
```

Here we define the method `match_str` which takes an argument `label`. `label` is a string slice which also has the lifetime `'b` - so it must last at least as long as the `self` that the method is called on.

In your original code, you had something like this:

```
impl Game<'_> {
    fn match_str<'a>(&mut self, label: &'a str) {
    ...
    }
}
```

This was telling the compiler:

- That you are starting a new impl block that, and there are no lifetimes declared at impl level
- That the implementation is for the struct `Game`; this struct has a lifetime parameter but we don't care about it and we are not going to tie it to any element of the implementation
- We are defining a method `match_str`, and we are declaring a lifetime `'a` which we can refer to in the rest of the function signature
- We have an argument `label` which has the lifetime `a`, but we aren't relating this lifetime to anything else

---

More information:

- [Rust Book - Lifetime Annotations in Struct Definitions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#lifetime-annotations-in-struct-definitions)
- [Rust Book - Lifetime Annotations in Method Definitions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#lifetime-annotations-in-method-definitions)

Comment: Wonderful explanation. The breakdown provided the info I needed. Also great to have the doc reference  I had missed the detail that impl lifetime indicates that `self` inside this implementation will automatically have impl lifetime.

Comment: Game changing explanation @harmic. One small query regarding the last point "but we aren't relating this lifetime to anything else". If `match_str` returns a reference(and we specify lifetime `a), then that would mean that we are relating the lifetime of return value to `label: &'a str`?

Comment: @HarisMuzaffar yes, if we had this `fn match_str<'a>(&mut self, label: &'a str) -> &'a str` then the returned value has a lifetime no longer than the `label` parameter. Also note that  if you return a reference from a method and do not annotate it's lifetime, then it will automatically have the same lifetime as `self` (this is called [lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-elision.html))

Answer (score 1):

> How do I resolve this error?

Remove the generic lifetime from the function, provide a name for the lifetime on the `impl` block instead of using the anonymous lifetime, then use the named lifetime in the function arguments. Remove the lifetime from `&self`:

```
impl<'a> Game<'a> {
    fn match_str(&mut self, label: &'a str, match_literal: &'a str, f: fn(&str) -> Option<&str>) {
        self.handlers.push(LineHandlerInfo {
            label,
            match_literal,
            f,
        });
    }
}
```

See also:

- [Cannot borrow as mutable more than once at a time in one code - but can in another very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31067031/155423)

> What exactly am I doing when I use the "anonymous lifetime" in impl?

You are effectively stating "I know there's a lifetime here, but I don't care about it". However, that's not true for your case; you do care about the lifetime that parameterizes the type because that's what your variables need to match.

See also:

- [`'_`, the anonymous lifetime](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/ownership-and-lifetimes/the-anonymous-lifetime.html) in the Edition Guide

> for a struct with a function pointer in it

This has nothing to do with function pointers. When encountering problems while programing, I recommend creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), stripping out things that don't make the error go away. This allows you to focus on exactly the problem at hand. For example, this reproduces the same error:

```
struct Game<'a> {
    handlers: Vec<&'a str>,
}

impl Game<'_> {
    fn match_str<'a>(&mut self, label: &'a str) {
        self.handlers.push(label);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ultrasaurus there are more [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here.

Comment: I still don't understand what is is exactly about the example that means that an anonymous lifetime won't work. For other examples where the struct has a named lifetime don't need a named lifetime for impl.

Comment: The isolated example that is provided in this answer shows a different error.  I attempted to apply the fix and still see the same error: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c7b05b72fcaf32e3dde9b761661ce556

Comment: You did not apply the same fix. The function should not have any generic lifetimes.

Comment: I've updated the question with a smaller example that also adds more explicitly named lifetimes in all of the places where I know to add them.  The information in this answer was helpful, but I'm still not seeing where there remains a generic lifetime and how to resolve the error.

Comment: @Ultrasaurus then it’s a duplicate of the question I’ve linked in this answer and another one I’ll have to find tomorrow and the effort of this answer has been invalidated. You are trying to store something with lifetime X in a struct that holds lifetime Y. There’s no relation between those two, so the compiler fails. Additionally, you are saying that the lifetime of the thing you are storing has to be exactly the same as the thing you store it in, which is almost never possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200991/discussion-between-ultrasaurus-and-shepmaster).