# Passing lifetime to a struct

Tags: rust, reference, traits, lifetime

I have code like this:

```
pub trait Action {
    fn execute(&self);
}

struct AddAction<'a> {
    rpn_calculator: &'a RpnCalculator
}

struct DeductAction<'a> {
    rpn_calculator: &'a RpnCalculator
}

impl Action for DeductAction<'_> {
    fn execute(&self) {
        // ...
    }
}

impl Action for AddAction<'_> {
    fn execute(&self) {
        // ...
    }
}

impl<'a> RpnCalculator {
    fn actions(&self) -> Vec<Box<dyn Action + 'a>> {
        let mut actions: Vec<Box<dyn Action + 'a>> = vec![
            Box::new(AddAction { rpn_calculator: &self })
            Box::new(AddAction { rpn_calculator: &self })
            // ...
        ];
        // ...
        actions
    }
}
```

The intention of my code is that RpnCalculator.actions() should create some instances of some structs that implement trait Action and return a vector containing those instances. Those structs have a property rpn_calculator which is a reference to a RpnCalculator. The RpnCalculator.actions() should put self (the RpnCalculator that creates it) into this reference.

Now the error I get is "cannot infer the appropiate lifetime". I get this error in the line where I create an instance that I add to the vector:

```
Box::new(AddAction { rpn_calculator: &self })
```

For that reason I have `'a` in the vector declaration, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to infer an appropriate lifetime for an implementation using lifetimes for structs and impl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58422765/how-to-infer-an-appropriate-lifetime-for-an-implementation-using-lifetimes-for-s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use `fn actions(&'a self)` because the lifetime
`'a` you use in `dyn Action + 'a` is related to the lifetime
of the `RpnCalculator`.