# cannot borrow `xxx` as mutable more than once at a time when using mpd's Query::and

Tags: rust

I am trying to realize the following function, which takes 3 optional input and get search result from mpd client from the rust-mpd crate.

```rust
fn load(
    &mut self,
    track: &Option<String>,
    artist: &Option<String>,
    album: &Option<String>
) -> Result<(), &'static str>{
    println!("mpd, load method is invoked with:");
    let mut query = Query::new();

    if let Some(s) = track {
        println!("  track: {}", &s);
        query.and(Term::Tag(Cow::Borrowed("track")), s);
    }

    if let Some(s) = artist {
        println!("  artist: {}", &s);
        query.and(Term::Tag(Cow::Borrowed("artist")), s);
    }

    if let Some(s) = album {
        println!("  album: {}", &s);
        query.and(Term::Tag(Cow::Borrowed("album")), s);
    }

    //let musics = self.client.search(&query, Window(None));
    let musics = self.client.search(&query, (1,2));
    println!("Search result: {:?}", musics);

    Ok(())
}
```

However, when I try to compile, it tells me:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `query` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/player/mpd.rs:62:13
   |
57 |             query.and(Term::Tag(Cow::Borrowed("track")), s);
   |             ----- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
62 |             query.and(Term::Tag(Cow::Borrowed("artist")), s);
   |             ^^^^^
   |             |
   |             second mutable borrow occurs here
   |             first borrow later used here

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `query` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/player/mpd.rs:67:13
   |
62 |             query.and(Term::Tag(Cow::Borrowed("artist")), s);
   |             ----- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
67 |             query.and(Term::Tag(Cow::Borrowed("album")), s);
   |             ^^^^^
   |             |
   |             second mutable borrow occurs here
   |             first borrow later used here

error[E0502]: cannot borrow `query` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/player/mpd.rs:71:41
   |
67 |             query.and(Term::Tag(Cow::Borrowed("album")), s);
   |             ----- mutable borrow occurs here
...
71 |         let musics = self.client.search(&query, (1,2));
   |                                         ^^^^^^
   |                                         |
   |                                         immutable borrow occurs here
   |                                         mutable borrow later used here
```

If my way is wrong, how should I achieve the same functionality?

Answer (score 3):

On first sight, the mutable borrow should end with the `if let` block, which would allow the subsequent borrows. However there is a bug in `rust-mpd` that causes the borrow to be extended for the full lifetime of `query`: the [`Query::and`](http://kstep.me/rust-mpd/mpd/search/struct.Query.html#method.and) method is declared as:

```
fn and<'b: 'a, V: 'b + Into<Cow<'b, str>>>(
    &'a mut self,         // <- Note the 'a lifetime here
    term: Term<'b>,
    value: V)
    -> &'a mut Query<'a>  // <- Note the **two** 'a lifetimes here
```

using the same lifetime `'a` for both the references to the query *and* the embedded lifetime. The method should be declared like this:

```
fn and<'b: 'a, V: 'b + Into<Cow<'b, str>>>(
    &mut self,
    term: Term<'b>,
    value: V)
    -> &mut Query<'a>
```

You should report a bug to `rust-mpd`.

Comment: Feel free to point the mpd maintainer to [Cannot borrow as mutable more than once at a time in one code - but can in another very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31067031/155423)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to use the library in its non-ideal state, you can iteratively update a mutable reference to the `Query`, instead of using it directly:

```
use mpd::{Query, Term}; // 0.0.12
use std::borrow::Cow;

fn load(
    track: &Option<String>,
    artist: &Option<String>,
    album: &Option<String>,
) -> Result<(), &'static str> {
    let mut query = Query::new();
    let mut query = &mut query;

    if let Some(s) = track {
        query = query.and(Term::Tag(Cow::Borrowed("track")), s);
    }

    if let Some(s) = artist {
        query = query.and(Term::Tag(Cow::Borrowed("artist")), s);
    }

    if let Some(s) = album {
        query = query.and(Term::Tag(Cow::Borrowed("album")), s);
    }

    let mut client = mpd::Client::new(std::fs::File::open("/tmp/junk").unwrap()).unwrap();
    let _musics = client.search(&query, (1, 2));

    Ok(())
}
```