# Confused by Rust closure lifetime

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime

I ran into a confusing situation where what the compiler outputs doesn't logically make sense.
Here is the minimal example to reproduce the same issue I'm having with my project code.

```
use std::sync::Arc;

struct A<'a, T> {
    f: Box<dyn Fn(&u32) -> T + 'a>
}

struct B<'a> {
    inner: A<'a, Z<'a>>
}

impl<'a, T> A<'a, T> {
    fn new<F>(f: F) -> Self where F: Fn(&u32) -> T + 'a {
        A { f: Box::new(f) }
    }
}

struct X<'a> {
    _d: &'a std::marker::PhantomData<()>
}

struct Z<'a> {
    _d: &'a std::marker::PhantomData<()>
}

impl<'a> X<'a> {
    fn g(&self, y: u32) -> Z {
        Z { _d: &std::marker::PhantomData }
    }
}

impl<'a> B<'a> {
    fn new(x: Arc<X<'a>>) -> Self {
        B {
            inner: A::new(move |y: &u32| -> Z {
                x.g(*y)
            })
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
}
```

And the confusing compilation error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in function call due to conflicting requirements
  --> t.rs:35:19
   |
35 |                 x.g(*y)
   |                   ^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime '_ as defined on the body at 34:27...
  --> t.rs:34:27
   |
34 |             inner: A::new(move |y: &u32| -> Z {
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that closure can access `x`
  --> t.rs:35:17
   |
35 |                 x.g(*y)
   |                 ^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 31:6...
  --> t.rs:31:6
   |
31 | impl<'a> B<'a> {
   |      ^^
   = note: ...so that the expression is assignable:
           expected B<'a>
              found B<'_>

error: aborting due to previous error
```

What I don't quite get is what "the lifetime" refers to as mentioned in the log, and what exactly that anonymous lifetime `'_` stands for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a small oversight in your code. It should be:

```rust
impl<'a> X<'a> {
    fn g(&self, y: u32) -> Z<'a> {
        Z { _d: &std::marker::PhantomData }
    }
}
```

The whole thing then compiles. This is an example of Rust's [lifetime elision  rule](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/nomicon/lifetime-elision.html) coming into play.

According to the relevant elision rules, namely:

> - Each elided lifetime in input position becomes a distinct lifetime parameter.
> - If there are multiple input lifetime positions, but one of them is `&self` or `&mut self`, the lifetime of `self` is assigned to all elided output lifetimes.

Then to `rustc` your original code will actually be like following:

```rust
impl<'a> X<'a> {
    fn g<'b>(&'b self, y: u32) -> Z<'b> {
        Z { _d: &std::marker::PhantomData }
    }
}
```

The elided lifetime parameter `'b` will come from the calling site, which is exactly what you saw in the error message. The `rustc` couldn't reconcile the two lifetimes, hence the error.

Comment: Thanks for asking so promptly! So I do know about the elision rule... and actually I wrote 'b explicitly previously. But what I didn't quite get, intuitively, is why rustc couldn't reconcile the two lifetimes. Could you point that out?

Comment: @Determinant I believe that's because the variance. Unless you explicitly define `'b: 'a`, the lifetimes in Rust are invariant, meaning there's no relationship between them. That's what `rustc` tells you in the error message, `'_` and `'a` are two different lifetimes.

Comment: I also tried that, but without luck...Could you show how to do it (with 'b: 'a bound) correctly? I think that'd be very educational.

Comment: So my reasoning was: although the def for `g` doesn't specify the relation between `'a` and the implicit `'b`, `x.g` still gives the information that `&self` in g, i.e. `'b` should be bounded by the lifetime of `x`, which is bounded by `Arc<X<'a>>`, which is bounded by `'a`. So in this sense, `'a` should outlive `'b`? Most part of my confusion came from this.

Comment: @Determinant a flaw in your reasoning, *`'b` should be bounded by the lifetime of `x`, which is bounded by `Arc<X<'a>>`*. Not true, remember a closure is a suspended computing, which doesn't happen yet. `'b` is only materialized  whenever `B::inner::f` is called. `rustc` can't possibly know what that is. So unless it can statically determines all lifetimes involved, it will complain. `fn g(&self, y: u32) -> Z<'a>` does just that, which was the only place in your original code that depended on elided lifetime.

Comment: Minor correction: relationships between lifetimes are a different thing from [variance](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nomicon/subtyping.html), which is a relationship between a type constructor and its parameter. I don't know if there's a good name for the relationships between lifetimes but you could say that `'b` and `'a` are *independent* unless explicitly constrained. (Actually, because `'b` is already constrained not to strictly outlive `'a`, they are only partially independent; adding `'b: 'a` would constrain them to be the same.)

Comment: @trentcl thanks, saying they are independent would be better.

Comment: @trentcl I see. So `rustc` does know that `'a: 'b` has to hold -- which is what I thought. But no matter how I annotate the other part `'b: 'a`, the compiler still doesn't seem to like what I assert...Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: `'b: 'a` is a mistake because it says that `'b` must outlive `'a`. `'a` must already outlive `'b`, so adding the annotation just says that `'a` and `'b` must be the exact *same* lifetime -- in other words, it's equivalent to `fn g(&'a self, y: u32) -> Z<'a>`. Writing `&'a self` is nearly always a mistake because it forces `self` to be borrowed for `'a`, and when `'a` is the lifetime of something inside `self`, the lifetimes can become overconstrained. [This recent question is about a bug in a library caused by just such a misplaced `'a`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58878192/3650362)

Comment: Applied to your problem, you can't make `new` compile by *adding* a constraint to `g` (forcing `'b` to outlive / be the same as `'a`), because the problem is that the constraints are contradictory. You need to *remove* a constraint  (allow `'b` to be independent of `'a`).