# Cannot mutate variable wrapped in a static Lazy<Mutex<_>> because it does not live long enough

Tags: rust, static, global-variables, lifetime

I need to access and modify a static variable:

```rust
mod my_mod {
    use std::collections::HashMap;

    pub enum MyA<'a> {
        Instance(&'a MyC<'a>),
        Another,
    }

    pub struct MyC<'a> {
        field: &'a str,
    }

    pub struct MyB<'a> {
        map: HashMap<i32, MyC<'a>>,
    }
    impl<'a> MyB<'a> {
        pub fn new() -> Self {
            MyB {
                map: HashMap::new(),
            }
        }
        pub fn insert<'b: 'a>(&'b mut self, k: i32) -> MyA {
            let v = MyC { field: "hello" };
            self.map.insert(k, v);
            MyA::Instance(self.map.get(&k).unwrap())
        }
    }
}

use crate::my_mod::{MyA, MyB};
use once_cell::sync::Lazy;
use std::sync::Mutex;

static MYB: Lazy<Mutex<MyB>> = Lazy::new(|| Mutex::new(MyB::new()));

fn my_func() -> i32 {
    let mut my_b = MYB.lock().unwrap();
    let my_a = { my_b.insert(1) };
    match my_a {
        MyA::Instance(s) => 1,
        MyA::Another => 2,
    }
}

fn main() {
    my_func();
}
```

My dependencies:

```
[dependencies]
once_cell = "1.8.0"
```

The error:

```
error[E0597]: `my_b` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:38:18
   |
38 |     let my_a = { my_b.insert(1) };
   |                  ^^^^----------
   |                  |
   |                  borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                  argument requires that `my_b` is borrowed for `'static`
...
43 | }
   | - `my_b` dropped here while still borrowed
```

It tells me that `my_b` is dropped at the end of `my_func` but the reference needs to be valid for the whole program run, if that is what `'static` means. Why does it have to be valid for `'static`? Is it a problem with lifetime parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the incorrect lifetime annotations on `MyB::insert`:

```
fn insert(&mut self, k: i32)
```

When you say `insert<'b: 'a>(&'b mut self`, that [means that `'b` outlives `'a`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/trait-bounds.html#lifetime-bounds).

In your case, `my_b` is a `MutexGuard`. When you call `insert`, you dereference the guard and so `&'b self` has lifetime *of the mutex guard*. You are attempting to store  a `'static` string into the map, so `'a` is `'static`. The guard **does not** outlive `'static`.

See also:

- [Cannot borrow as mutable more than once at a time in one code - but can in another very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31067031/155423)
- [Why does linking lifetimes matter only with mutable references?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32165917/155423)

Comment: So there would be a difference if `MyC::field` was not a string literal but a reference to something with a non-static lifetime? Maybe my example was not hundered percent matching with the original code then. Thanks anyway, still helped me a lot!